# mongoexport only exporting first element of an array

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongoexport

My data structure looks like below:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "timestamp": "1234567",
    "details": [
        {
            "data": "343434343"

        }
        {
            "data": "66666666"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I type my command into shell (below), it only outputs the first element of the `details` array

Command:

```
mongoexport --port 27017 --collection mycol --db mydb --out example.csv --type csv --fields timestamp,details.0.data
```

How do I get ALL the elements of the array exported to CSV?

Comment: Number of sub documents within the `details` element is fixed or can it be vary ?

Comment: @PSJ Can vary. Is there a way? I'm pulling my hair out

Comment: CSV is flat structure file. How will you represent array in CSV? one solution is to concatenate items of array into one delimited string and export.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `details.0.data` in your `--fields` option, the `.0` means "select only the first array element", which is the one with index zero.

You should remove the `.0.data` from your query, like so:

```
mongoexport --port 27017 --collection mycol --db mydb --out example.csv --type csv --fields timestamp,details
```

This should output all elements of the `details` array in your `example.csv` file.

Check out the MongoDB documentation on this topic: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-for-an-element-by-the-array-index-position